# Ordenar array de strings por el primer valor

Tags: python

Estoy iniciándome en python y tengo problemas para ordenar el siguiente array de strings

```
["DG1000420,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999",
"DG1000421,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999",
"DG1000422,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999",
"DG1000420,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998",
"DG1000421,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998",
"DG1000422,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998",
"DG1000420,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998",
"DG1000421,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998",
"DG1000422,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998",
"DG1000420,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999",
"DG1000421,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999",
"DG1000422,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999",
"DG1000420,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996",
"DG1000421,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996",
"DG1000422,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996",
"DG1000420,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997",
"DG1000421,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997",
"DG1000422,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997",
"DG1000420,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999",
"DG1000421,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999",
"DG1000422,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999",
"DG1000420,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.799999,38.34",
"DG1000421,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.9999,38.34",
"DG1000422,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.799999,38.34"]
```

Me gustaria que el nuevo array quedara ordenado por el primer valor del string, tal que:

```
["DG1000420,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999",
"DG1000420,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998",
"DG1000420,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998",
```

He intentando usando collections.OrderedDict pero me ha sido imposible.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: por favor muestra exactamente qué intentaste, para poder empezar a partir de allí. Por otra parte, siempre es útil un ejemplo mínimo para que quede más claro que con muchísimas líneas

Comment: Es muy importante lo que comenta fedorqui, creo que lo que realmente quieres es ordenar teniendo en cuenta el contenido de la cadena hasta la primera coma (DG1000420, DG1000421, etc). Aún así queda una duda, ante DG100 y DG23 por ejemplo cual va primero, si ordenamos lexicográficamente es DG100 pero si tenemos en cuenta el valor numérico por separado sería DG23... No se si esta última situación puede darse (longitud diferente) pero conviene aclararlo. Por cierto, parece un csv, ¿por qué no o parseas directamente para separar columnas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a ordenar con `sort`.

```
array.sort();

print(array);
```

Resultado

```
['DG1000420,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999', 'DG1000420,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998', 'DG1000420,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998', 'DG1000420,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999', 'DG1000420,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996', 'DG1000420,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997', 'DG1000420,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999', 'DG1000420,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.799999,38.34', 'DG1000421,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999', 'DG1000421,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998', 'DG1000421,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998', 'DG1000421,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999', 'DG1000421,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996', 'DG1000421,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997', 'DG1000421,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999', 'DG1000421,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.9999,38.34', 'DG1000422,2013-12-01,36.719997,36.18,35.639999', 'DG1000422,2013-12-02,32.399998,32.939999,32.399998', 'DG1000422,2013-12-03,53.819996,53.099998,52.739998', 'DG1000422,2013-12-04,52.019997,53.279999,50.939999', 'DG1000422,2013-12-05,54.359997,53.639999,53.819996', 'DG1000422,2013-12-06,51.839996,51.659996,52.199997', 'DG1000422,2013-12-07,49.139999,47.879997,46.619999', 'DG1000422,2013-12-08,38.879997,37.799999,38.34']
```

Comment: No me imaginaba que fuera tan facil. Ordena correctamente cada uno de los arrays por el primer valor del string. Gracias

Comment: @RaulA.R para eso estamos ;). Si consideras la pregunta resuelta márcala para quede como respondida.